# Where is Textured Coordinates?

Tags: texturing

For some reason whenever I try to find the "textured coordinate" node in blender, it never shows up. I tried seeing if this was a problem for anyone else, but it wasn't. Was the node named to something else? Or is my version of blender just broken? [image: When I try looking up tex to find the node]

Answer (score 2):

It's in the "Input" section of the "Add" menu (4th from the bottom).

There may be another issue (like you're looking at the world shader, or nodes are enabled). More can be determined if you share a full screenshot of the node editor.